# PHP sorted associate numeric key array passing to ajax not work

Tags: php, ajax, arrays, sorting

I have a function return an associate numeric key array:

```
public static function getSortedFruits()
{
$fruits = array('100' => 'lemon', '102' => 'orange', '103' => 'apple', '204' => 'banana');
asort($fruits);
print_r($fruits); // return sorted array('103' => 'apple', '204' => 'banana', '100' => 'lemon', '102' => 'orange')
return $fruits;
}
```

i call this function from PHP code, the array is sorted

```
$fruits = getSortedFruits(); // sorted array
```

when I call this function from ajax, the array is the same as before, isn't sorted

```
$('#fruits').bind('change', function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/ajax/getFruits', // route to getFruits function
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(result) {
               console.log(result); // the array isn't sorted
            });
});
```

If the key of the $fruits is not numeric, such as a, b, c, the result is sorted as normally both function call and ajax request.

Comment: How is ajax getting generated ?

Comment: I think you should use `echo json_encode($fruits);`.

Answer (score 1):

***asort*** method sorts based on array **values**. There is no difference in order from outputs from print_r and json_encode.

```
$fruits = array('1' => 'lemon', '2' => 'orange', '3' => 'apple', '4' => 'banana');
asort($fruits);

print_r($fruits);
// Above outputs:Array ( [3] => apple [4] => banana [1] => lemon [2] => orange )

echo json_encode($fruits);
// Above outputs: {"3":"apple","4":"banana","1":"lemon","2":"orange"}
```

Comment: I believe the poster wants to sort by array values as asort does.

Comment: With `asort` I am getting correct result in print_r and json_encode. So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Updated answer, with outputs. Please remove downvote!

Comment: if I return json_encode, the javascript get sorted array but when I parse the result to javascript object, the array is autosorted by key.
success: function(result) {
   console.log(result); // sorted by value
   var result2 = JSON.parse(result);
   console.log(result2); // sorted by key AUTOMACTICALLY.
}

Comment: If you need sorting based on value, you already have it through first method. If using jQuery, no need to use JSON.parse, as data is already parsed in json object. Makes sense ?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code on my local pc with xampp, you will have to use

`print_r($fruits)`

**Or**

`echo json_encode($fruits);`

**Instead of**

`return $fruits`

**UPDATED**

encode the array after returned function `getSortedFruits()`, something like

```
$fruits = getSortedFruits(); // sorted array
json_encode($fruits)
```

Comment: This function is used in both ajax request and call from other function. so I can't return json_encode

Comment: I've updated my code. Sorry if it wasn't clear for u all

Comment: the error is: when i pass a json array with numeric key to javascript, it automatically convert all key to integer and automatically sort array by key. So the sorted array is sorted again.
json: {"5":"apple", "3":"lemon"} is automatically converted to {3: "lemon", 5: "apple"}. It's not my expectation.